# How to sort dates in java?

Tags: java, sorting, date

I have below data for date with timestamp which is stored in hash map and I want to sort the dates in java.
Please suggest how to do it?

```
Key ---> value
301.html --> Thu, 11 Apr 2019 11:23:13 GMT
k/302.html --> Thu, 11 Apr 2019 11:44:58 GMT
/ --> Thu, 11 Apr 2019 11:48:25 GMT
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have already tried and which is not working for you.

Comment: What are you expecting as output? A list of dates? Some sort of sorted hashmap? Something else? Also, yes, please add the code you already have with some sample input.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> l = new ArrayList<>(dateMap.entrySet())
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(entry -> {
                try {
                    return format.parse(entry.getValue()).getTime();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Wrong date format");
                }
            })).collect(Collectors.toList());
```